# How to insert images from render( , , context) in Django?

Tags: python, django

guys! New in Django so maybe it's a silly question. I have a .json file that keeps information about shop's clothes including "img". The goal is to otput all the information about products in a single "for loop". So I've written such lines

```
{% for product in products %}

                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                    <div class="card h-100">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="card-img-top"
                                 src="{% static '{{ product.img }}' %}"  !!! problem is here
                                 alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">
                                <a href="#"> {{ product.name }} </a>
                            </h4>
                            <h5>{{ product.price }}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text"> {{ product.description }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Отправить в корзину</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
```

Everything works fine except the line concerns an image. In devtools I get the next path "/static/%7B%7B%20product.img%20%7D%7D". But in the .json file it looks like "img": "vendor/img/products/Brown-sports-oversized-top-ASOS-DESIGN.png". I am totally confused about that situation and definitely in a bind. I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

work with:

```
<img src="{{ product.img.url }}">
```

if the image is effective (`product.img` is not `None`), and you [added the media urls to the `urls.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development), then it will determine the URL where to fetch the product image.

Note that in production, Django does *not* serve media files, so in that case you will need to configure the webserver (Apache, Nginx, etc.) to serve media files for you.

Comment: I've just played around with "/static/%7B%7B%20product.img%20%7D%7D" and found out what %7B%7B%20 meant. Then deleted trailing and facing symbols '{{ and now it's working correctly. Excuse me for holding you up